# Firebase REST Api based Realtime database access from AppEngine URLFetch

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-realtime-database, urlfetch

Due to App engine Quota, I have to find an alternative for accessing firebase realtime database from app engine. I had a though about using firebase REST apis with URLFetch service of google app engine.  I tried but its not updating my firebase database.

```
 String surl = "https://MyApplication.firebaseio.com/";

        URLFetchService urlFetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();

        URL url = new URL(surl);
        FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults();
        fetchOptions.doNotValidateCertificate();
        fetchOptions.doNotFollowRedirects();
        fetchOptions.setDeadline(60D);
        HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST, fetchOptions);

        request.setPayload("{ 'key': 'Some Kind of Value' }".getBytes());
        HTTPResponse httpResponse = urlFetchService.fetch(request);
```

Comment: What does the HTTP response look like?

Comment: More info would be helpful.  What is the response, does your path have write security rules?, etc.